# Access denied whe uploading a file

Tags: file-upload, access-denied

this is strange and i do not have a reasonable explanation.
If i connect to SP via browser, i have access to the library and the folders and can upload files.
But if i connect to SP via powershell i can connect, i see the library and i can get a list of all folders in the library via

```
$Folders = Get-PnPFolder -List $LibraryURL
```

But running the commands

```
$TargetFolderURL = $LibraryURL + "/" + $FolderName
Add-PnPFile -Path "$($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)" -Folder $TargetFolderURL -Values @{"Title" = $($File.Name)} | Out-Null
```

Return an Access Denied error.
Manually uploading the same file, logged in as the same user, works as expected. So, i expect my user has access and has been granted Write privileges to the folder.

What am i doing wrong?